# Formatting in <script> is broken in jinja-html by vs-code

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, jinja2

Auto formatting of {{}} and other formatting in  in jinja-html with broken formatting like below by VS-code.

```html
 <script>
      let barData = {
        labels: [
          {% for item in labels %}
      "{{ item }}"
      {% endfor %}
          ],
      datasets: [{
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: [
          {% for item in values %}
            "{{ item }}"
            {% endfor %}
      ]}]
      }
```

- What we tried

```html
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"jinja-html": "html",
"erb": "html"
},
"[python]": {
"editor.tabSize": 4
},
"files.associations": {
"*.html": "jinja-html"
},
```

to the settingjson.
The wavy lines are gone, and emmet can be used, but
The formatting is off and not clean.
Even if I fix it manually, it reverts back to the original when automatically formatted.

- Supplemental Information

vscode
Mac
emmet

```html
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
"jinja-html": "html",
"erb": "html"
},
"[python]": {
"editor.tabSize": 4
},
"files.associations": {
"*.html": "jinja-html"
},
```

Extension: better jinja

-What we want to achieve

I want to be clean format.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why loop your dictionaries? you can fill in automatically:

```
<script>
  let barData = {
    labels: {{labels|tojson or []}},
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: {{values|tojson or []}}
  }]
  }
```

But i think you can resolve your problem, commenting your for and endfor tags:

```
<script>
  let barData = {
    labels: [
      //{% for item in labels %}
         "{{ item }}"
      //{% endfor %}
      ],
  datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [
      //{% for item in values %}
        "{{ item }}"
      //{% endfor %}
  ]}]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help this you.

```
<script>
  let barData = {
    labels: JSON.parse(`{{labels|tojson or []}}`),
    datasets: [{
      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
      data: JSON.parse(`{{values|tojson or []}}`)
    }]
  }
</script>
```